# Approval workflow issue

Tags: workflow

I have created a simple approval workflow with 2 stages for a document library. User A will approve and then the approval has to go to User B

User A is receiving a mail and editing the document and saving it. User A then goes to his mail and approves it.

Now as per the logic, the User B should get an email. But its not happening so.

Is it something that I'm missing? Or should I include all the users in a single stage?

Please suggest

Comment: Sure that the user B is the owner of the task after the approval by the user A? occurs in history "as workflow" who is the current owner of the task

Comment: do you have an if-condition to start the second workflow?

Comment: @Stefano: Where can I find the current owner of the task? In the WF history its mentioned that "The workflow could not set content approval status. Enable content moderation for this list and run the workflow again."

Comment: Select the item and click on Workflows ribbon, the next screen you should see the history of the tasks associated with the described

Comment: @Stefano: I did check the history. It says that it failed to start. The workflow could not set content approval status. Enable content moderation for this list and run the workflow again.

Comment: wait :) how you created this workflow? GUI/Designer/Visual Studio

Comment: Default Approval 2010 workflow :)

Comment: OK I did test the same functionality in SP2013 and its working. But its not working on SP2010...weird!!!